# SharePoint 2016 send email error, certificate validation errors

Tags: sharepoint-server, outgoing-email, tls

I'm facing an issue when trying to send emails from SharePoint, I get one of the error messages below:

```
An operation failed because the following certificate has validation errors:
  Subject Name: CN=mailservername
  Issuer Name: CN=mailservername
  Thumbprint: 645B2D4B72573478DBD162F39AAE0260B25F6582
  Errors: SSL policy errors have been encountered.  Error code '0x6'..
```

```
An operation failed because the following certificate has validation errors:
  Subject Name: CN=mailservername
  Issuer Name: CN=mailservername
  Thumbprint: 645B2D4B72573478DBD162F39AAE0260B25F6582
  Errors: The root of the certificate chain is not a trusted root authority..
```

I have a single server farm, with SharePoint server 2016

When I configured the outgoing emails with the exchange server as provided by the IT team (mail.organizationname.gov.xx) or the server IP, I get the first error message.

When I configured it with the mail server name as mentioned in the error (either as is, or with domain (FQDM)) I get the second error !

Any help would be highly appreciated

Thank you

---

Edit: I'm sending the emails via PowerShell

Comment: have you checked Certificate store and this Certificate (with the Thumbprint) if the root is alright on Sharepoint servers? You probably need to install Root Certificate for him, or try to check this on the Mail Server

Comment: @ZdeněkVinduška Thanks alot for your quick reply, As for the solution, to be honest certificates are not my thing, I'm not very familiar with them, can you further explain what to do ! is it the certlm.msc we are taking about ! and where to check the certificate

Comment: open mmc.msc then Add CTRL+M certificate store https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-view-certificates-with-the-mmc-snap-in and find certificate with your thumbnail and check the Cert Path if Root Certificate is correct. https://support.nmi.com/hc/en-gb/articles/115002011366-How-to-Check-if-the-Correct-Certificates-Are-Installed-on-Windows

Comment: @ZdeněkVinduška I've tried to find the certificate on the SP server, but it seems like it's not there, I don't have direct access to SMTP server since it's client environment.

Note that another environment was working fine without any certificates !

Comment: so maybe thats a restriction on SMTP server, contant your Exchange guys, they will probably know a solution

Comment: @ZdeněkVinduška my Exchange guys are a client's IT team who deny they have any issue on their side, and that's the worst thing in the whole situation, as always thank you for your replies, much appreciated

Comment: but it retunrs to you a thumbprint of the certificate, so you should find this certificate on SP server and them on the MAIL server. They have some restrictions with emails? It must be Secured communication?

Comment: Your are totally right, It is a secure communication, "Use TLS" is required to be true, so should I have a certificate then ! I have never worked with secure emails before, what's the process, where should the certificate come from and where should it go,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to set SSL to Yes in Outgoing emails and Create TLS communication between SP and Exchange servers. [Manual here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mikelee/2017/12/22/configure-tls-encryption-between-sharepoint-on-premise-and-exchange/). They're resolving the same issue with certificate in 2nd half of manual.

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: Thank you, I have requested the certificate and waiting their response, and I'll upvote your answer and select as an answer when verified

Comment: You're welcome. You can already upvote now for help :)

Comment: I can't upvote you due to the lack of reputation, but I've selected your reply as an answer, ty

Comment: Ah, ok, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Zdeněk's answer, after referring to the article above, it turns out since I'm contacting the exchange server with TLS, the SendEmail via PowerShell won't work, and sending an email from SharePoint itself was already working, and I only tried PowerShell for testing purposes (Which I forgot to mention it in my question)

Thanks alot Zdeněk for your replies